# Set filename manually for FileUpload

Tags: java, gwt

The standard way for FileUpload is a browse button to allow user to select file to upload.

Is there a way to set the filename for `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload` manually? The only available method regarding this is `getFileName` but no `setFileName`

**Update:**

I'm not referring to GWT app accessing file system, just a way to set the filename to whatever filename, usually for blob / blob url created in the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since GWT converts to `Javascript/HTML.`

Due to security reasons `HTML/JavaScript` does'nt have allow to access local file system.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security

> JavaScript and the DOM provide the potential for malicious authors to deliver scripts to run on a client computer via the web. Browser authors contain this risk using two restrictions. First, scripts run in a sandbox in which they can only perform web-related actions, not general-purpose programming tasks like creating files. Second, scripts are constrained by the same origin policy: scripts from one web site do not have access to information such as usernames, passwords, or cookies sent to another site

You have to make a server request/change at server itself by sending that name in order to set the name to the resource.

In chrome You can try

```
yourForm.append("blob",blobObj, "yourFileName");
```

Spec:http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#interface-formdata

Comment: How do I upload a blob generated with Javascript? With JSNI that I get the blob URL?

Comment: var blob = items[i].getAsFile();

Answer (score 1):

As GWT generates HTML, and HTML does not allow this for security reasons, the answer is no.

You can have a look at the standard to see what you can do or not with FileUpload: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#file-upload-state-(type=file)

Comment: How do I upload a blob generated with Javascript? With JSNI that I get the blob URL?